# How to draw a bezier curve with textured color in iOS?

Tags: ios, drawing, textures

I want to simulate a paintbrush stroke when the user moves his finger to paint on the screen. I can record the coordinates of his stroke, and generate a Bezier curve with a certain width, but I don't want the curve to be a solid color, but textured like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this using UIKit's drawing utilities? (I want the texture to be stretched and curved along the Beizer curve)

I know there is `colorWithPatternImage`, but I'm not sure if that is what I want.

---

Similar questions (not working):

[How to achieve paint brush strokes in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487360/how-to-achieve-paint-brush-strokes-in-ios)

[2013, Existing package for drawing (painting, brush, lines) in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203391/2013-existing-package-for-drawing-painting-brush-lines-in-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1)